# GregorianCalendar give unexpected result for "Asia/Singapore" TimeZone and date of the system as 30th Jan 2014

Tags: java

I am facing an issue related to GregorianCalendar.

Prerequisit:
 System timeZone is : "Asia/Singapore"
 System Time is: 30 Jan 2014

Executed code:

```
 Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
 TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore");
 cal.setTimeZone(tz);
 cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);//1 is equivalent to Feb
 cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
 cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
 cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
 Date dte=cal.getTime();
```

**Actual Result:**  5th March 2014

**Expected Result:** 5th Feb 2014

But if i execute the same code with change in sequence it results in correct value:

```
 Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
 TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore");
 cal.setTimeZone(tz);
 cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
 cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
 cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);//1 is equivalent to Feb
 cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
```

It gives correct result

Can somebody help me to know the root cause of this?

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code. It's hard to read at the moment, and even in the question *source* you have a blank line between each useful line. Also, why are you calling `cal.get` at all?

Comment: Also, I've just run your first code snippet and the result was Wed Feb 05 04:56:23 GMT 2014. Can you verify that that *exact* code gives the wrong answer for you?

Comment: first code also gives correct outpul.

Comment: why are you using the noise statements like `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: note that the system time given in the question is crucial to the behaviour. Setting the Calendar to 30 Jan after getting it will show the problem.

Comment: @piet.t: Ah - I'd missed the "system time" part at the start of the question...

Answer (score 1):

When running your code on 30 Jan this will be the initial state of your calendar. `cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);` will then set the calendar to 30 Feb.
When calling `cal.get(DAY_OF_MONTH)` the internal state of the calendar will be recalculated to get the correct day. So 30 Feb be converted to 02 Mar since `cal.isLenient()` is true. 
Then setting the day to 30 will result in 30 Mar.

Try adding `cal.setLenient(false)` after creating your calendar and see how the first version of your code fails...

To fix your code remove get `cal.get()`-statements while your Calendar is in intermediate state to avoid premature recalculations.

EDIT: added part about `cal.get()`

Comment: After adding cal.setLenient(false) just after cal object creation   ,getting an error as below at line cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
Exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MONTH
        at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2482)
        at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:2469)
        at java.util.Calendar.complete(Calendar.java:1526)
        at java.util.Calendar.get(Calendar.java:1132)

Comment: ...as was expected since with setLenient(false) the Calendar doesn't allow to be set to 30 Feb - so this confirms the explanation made in my answer.